# list of wifi connections disappears after kernel update, kubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, kubuntu, broadcom

I have issues with wifi driver on my Kubuntu 16.04. bcmwl works fine with 4.4.0-31-generic (the oldest version of kernel on my system), but when kernel updates to different version list of wifi connections disappears. Previously i've fixed this by loading 4.4.0-31-generic and reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source from pool on Ubuntu installation stick. After reboot on newer kernel version Wifi worked like a charm, but now this trick did not work. I thought about restricting dkms to rebuild bcmwl during the upgrade, but do not know how to do it. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Probably the problem is in UEFI Secure Boot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the issue is about that kernel in particular? 
Why don't you try updating to the latest kernels? like 4.8 or 4.9?
The application: Ukuu (Ukuu kernel update utility)